# How to get "Location" response header using playwright?

Tags: typescript, request, playwright, playwright-typescript

**Problem:** I try to get all response headers using playwright request, but there no "Location" header. Could you help me how i can resolve the problem?

My code:

```
const pw = await request.newContext({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    extraHTTPHeaders: { 'my-device-id': 'value' } });

const response = await pw.post(fsUrl, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    form: {
                        UserName: usr.login,
                        Password: usr.password,
                        AuthMethod: 'FormsAuthentication',
                    },
                });

                console.log(response.headersArray());
```

Context:
playwright@1.42.1

I tried to add request header `'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Location',`

Comment: Does it return Location header if you send this request with Postman or curl?

Comment: With this amount of data it is just guessing...